# Using more than one condition with Where-Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

To remove the lines that contain the word **pizza** from the following text file:

```
The cat is my favorite animal.
I prefer pizza to vegetables.
My favorite color is blue.
Tennis is the only sport I like.
My favorite leisure time activity is reading books.
```

I ran the following code and it successfully removed the second line.

```
$inputFile =  "C:\Temp\Text.txt"
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'pizza'} | Set-Content "C:\Temp\Filtered.txt"
```

However, I haven't found a way to remove all occurrences of lines which contain either the word **pizza** or the word **sport**. I've tried to do this with this code:

```
$inputFile =  "C:\Temp\Text.txt"
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'pizza' -or $_ -notmatch 'sport'} | Set-Content "C:\Temp\Filtered.txt"
```

But it doesn't work as the output file is the same as the original one.

Comment: If you don't want to match either you need to use `-and` not `-or`. Otherwise you are only filtering out lines with both pizza and sport.

Comment: -and, not -or. And is inclusive, or is one or the other...

Comment: I find `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'pizza|sport'}` is a nicer way of matching multiple conditions

Comment: The question has few to do with PowerShell issues, it's about applying basic tautologies of [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus), particularly [De Morgan's Theorems (De Morgan's laws)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @JosefZ What I need to know is how to remove all the lines in my text file that contain the word 'pizza' or that contains the work 'sport' and I don't know how to do it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make yourself clear the *logic*.

First, use *positive condition* to **get** all the lines in my text file that **contain** the word 'pizza' **or**  the word 'sport':

```
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object {$_ -match 'pizza' -or $_ -match 'sport'}
```

Output should be

```
I prefer pizza to vegetables.
Tennis is the only sport I like.
```

Then, **negate** the condition to get desired result:

```
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object { -NOT ($_ -match 'pizza' -or $_ -match 'sport') }
```

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) allow rewriting the negated condition as

```
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object { $_ -NOTmatch 'pizza' -AND $_ -NOTmatch 'sport' }
```

The following script poses a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) (naive) implementation of *De Morgan's laws* in PowerShell:

```
''
'{0,-6} {1,-6}: {2,-7}  {3,-7}  {4,-7}  {5,-7}' -f 'P', 'Q', 'DM1a', 'DM1b', 'DM2a', 'DM2b'
''
ForEach ( $P in $True, $False ) { 
    ForEach ( $Q in $True, $False ) { 
        '{0,-6} {1,-6}: {2,-7}  {3,-7}  {4,-7}  {5,-7}' -f $P, $Q, 
            ( -not ( $P -and $Q ) -eq (      ( ( -not $P ) -or  ( -not $Q ) ) ) ),
            (      ( $P -and $Q ) -eq ( -not ( ( -not $P ) -or  ( -not $Q ) ) ) ),
            ( -not ( $P -or  $Q ) -eq (      ( ( -not $P ) -and ( -not $Q ) ) ) ),
            (      ( $P -or  $Q ) -eq ( -not ( ( -not $P ) -and ( -not $Q ) ) ) )
    }

}
```

**Output** (note that `DM2a` column covers your case):

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\tests\DeMorgan.ps1

P      Q     : DM1a     DM1b     DM2a     DM2b   

True   True  : True     True     True     True   
True   False : True     True     True     True   
False  True  : True     True     True     True   
False  False : True     True     True     True
```

Comment: Oh! I get it. Thanks you for taking the time to write this long explanation. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I find `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'this|that'}` is a nicer way of matching multiple conditions as the pipe acts as `-Or` for you.

```
$inputFile =  "C:\Temp\Text.txt"
Get-Content $inputFile | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'pizza|sport'} | Set-Content "C:\Temp\Filtered.txt"
```

Comment: It works and it's much more elegant! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also use the -in operator to test for the existence of your value in an array.

Comment: @blouskrine glad I could help :) If you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).